# How to see locally committed messages, but not pushed into git

Tags: git, commit

I know how to see commit messages in git by `git log` command, but it will list out all committed messages. What I want is those committed messages which have not been pushed that means only committed but not pushed. Do we have any command for this? I also have one solution, which is we can see all commits in github at the same time we can check with `git log` command. difference will be my output but I want this through command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a form of [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to show the difference between two branches:

```
git log origin/master..master
```

[More information](https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_log_dots.html) about different forms of `git-log`.

Even better (expanding on @PetSerAL's comment) you could create a handy alias to see the same information with:

```
 git config --global alias.justLocal "log @@{u}.."
```

So, whenever you wanted to see the results:

```
git justLocal
```

Comment: Nice. I thought of `git cherry` (not to be confused with `cherry-pick`).  `git cherry -v origin/master master` shows all commits in master that are not yet in origin/master prefixed with a `+`. But `git log`, esp. `git log --oneline` is _far_ better to read.